# How to check if a function is @parameterized in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameterized

How to check if a function in python is parameterized ?

For example :

```
@parameterized_expand(...)
def func():
      Do Something
```

How to check from another module whether func is `parameterized` ?

Comment: you mean if ```func``` has parameters or if func is decorated by the ```parameterized``` named function?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the inputs and desired outputs to demonstrate how this should work? I do not understand the quirestion in its current form. Additionally, `def func:` requires `()`, even if it has no parameteres